# Trying to use IF with Window Function

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    ID    Location      PrimaryLoc   Date            
    21     Tampa Beach    Y          2/23/16                 
    21     Miami beach    N          2/23/16            
    21     Hous           N          2/23/16
    375    LA             N          2/17/16
    375    SF             N          2/17/16
    375    SD             N          2/17/16
```

I need to pull back records where PrimaryLoc = 'Y', or, if there is no 'Y' then pull back the first 'N'(it doesn't really matter which 'N').

I was thinking a Window Function would work here.  I tried a simple one that populates the 'Y' with a 1 but I'm not sure how to get the 'N' if the ID doesn't have a 'Y'.  Maybe an IF type statement would work, but I've never done that in SQL.

This is what I have so far:

```
select *, sum(case when PrimaryLoc = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by ID, Location order by date)rn
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're right that a window function is the solution, but your implementation is way off.

I am assuming that you are grouping by `ID` only since that is the only column in your sample data that has duplicates.

This should do it:

```
WITH cte AS (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ID order by case when PrimaryLoc = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end, date) rn
from table
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PrimaryLoc DESC, [Date] DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: The problem with using RANK() is that it will return multiple results per ID if there is a tie in the ORDER BY.   My understanding is the OP wants only one result per ID, and if there is a tie, it doesn't matter which one gets returned.

Comment: @TabAlleman yeah, and I chose it specifically for it, in the case of more than one `Y`, but it really can be the wrong choice in case of more than one `N` on the same date

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The Row_Number() worked.  Rank() brought back all records = 'N' if there was no 'Y.'  It's frustrating that the answer really was simpler than what I was trying to do.  But I guess I'm still in the learning phase with Window Functions.